# Explanation of precedence required for function overloading with object types and generic T type

Tags: c#, generics, overloading, operator-precedence

I have following code and it is calling the param method every time. I dont know what is the precedence of each and why object type is not being called OR why params type function is called. But when i change s variable to object type the object type function is called. Sorry for my bad English.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "string";
        Invoke(s);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Invoke(object s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object Param Invoked");

    }
    static void Invoke<T>(params T[] values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Param method Invoked");

    }
```

Comment: The generic version effectively gives you a method with signature `Invoke(params string[] values)`, and `string` is more specific than `object`.

Comment: Because the generic method with a `string` type is a better match than `object`.  However if the variable is an object then the non-generic method is a better match .

Comment: This must have a duplicated questin, I recall exact same question last week ago, and it had a duplicate.